# STL transform is not working with BGL

Tags: boost, stl, graph

I'm new to BGL. I'm trying to transform a range of edges to equivalent objects usable in my system.

```
std::vector<my_obj*> return_value(distance(all_edges.first, all_edges.second));
std::transform(all_edges.first, all_edges.second, return_value.begin(),
               bind(&graph::transform, this, _1));
```

But I'm getting an error which I couldn't understand:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function `_OutputIterator std::transform(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _OutputIterator, _UnaryOperation) [with _InputIterator =boost::detail::adj_list_edge_iterator<std::_List_iterator<void*>, boo        st::detail::out_edge_iter<std::_List_iterator<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::        edge_bundle_t, my_obj*, boost::no_property> > >, void*, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::dir        ected_tag, void*>, ptrdiff_t>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directed        S, my_obj*, my_obj*, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, _OutputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_        iterator<my_obj**, std::vector<my_obj*, std::allocator<my_obj*> > >, _UnaryOperation = boost::la        mbda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::action<3, boost::lambda::        function_action<3, boost::lambda::detail::unspecified> >,
      2    boost::tuples::tuple<my_obj*(Graph::*const)(boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag        , void*>), Graph* const, const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >,boo        st::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_t        ype,boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> > >]':
      3 Isrc/icn_graph.cxx:70:   instantiated from here
      4 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:789: error:         no match for call to `(boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::        lambda::action<3, boost::lambda::function_action<3, boost::lambda::detail::unspecified> >, boost        ::tuples::tuple<my_obj*(Graph::*const)(boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, void*>        ), Graph* const, const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >, boost::tup        les::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, bo        ost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> > >) (boost::detail:        :edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, void*>)'
      5 /usr/include/boost/lambda/detail/lambda_functors.hpp:137: note: candidates are: typename T::sig<        boost::tuples::null_type>::type boost::lambda::lambda_functor<Base>::operator()() const [with T        = boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::action<3, boost::lambda::function_action<3,        boost::lambda::detail::unspecified> >, boost::tuples::tuple<my_obj*(Graph::*const)(boost::detail        ::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, void*>), Graph* const, const boost::lambda::lambda_functor        <boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tup        les::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, bo        ost::tuples::null_type> >]
      6 /usr/include/boost/lambda/detail/lambda_functors.hpp:145: note:                 typename T::sig<        boost::tuples::tuple<A&, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null        _type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tupl        es::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >::type boost::lambda::lambda        _functor<Base>::operator()(A&) const [with A = boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag        , void*>, T = boost::lambda::lambda_functor_base<boost::lambda::action<3, boost::lambda::functio        n_action<3, boost::lambda::detail::unspecified>>, boost::tuples::tuple<my_obj*(Graph::*const)(bo        ost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, void*>), Graph* const, const boost::lambda::lam        bda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >,boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,        boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null        _type, boost::tuples::null_type> >]
      7
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `all_edges` here?  If it is from `edges(g)`, the value type of the iterator is `edge_descriptor`, not `my_obj*`.  You will need to apply a different `std::transform` functor that gets your edge property from the descriptor then applies `graph::transform` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this, but I suspect that the line

```
bind(&graph::transform, this, _1)
```

is intended to mean "a unary function that takes in a `this` pointer and then invokes `graph::transform` on it."  If so, unfortunately this line doesn't do what you think it does.  It instead binds the current `this` pointer as the argument to `graph::transform`, then returns a functor to apply `graph::transform` to the current object.  I think what you probably want is something more along the lines of

```
std::mem_fun(&graph::transform)
```

Which does actually turn `graph::transform` into a unary function that invokes the given member function using its argument as the `this` pointer.  You actually probably want to use `boost::mem_fn` for this, but I'm not an expert on how it works and won't try to guess the correct answer here. :-)

If I'm totally wrong about what you're trying to do here, let me know and I'll remove this answer.

Comment: according to [boost documentation] (boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/lambda/…) I can use bind with member function like this: bind(&graph::transform, <object_pointer>, <arg or placeholder>) It happened that the posted two lines are inside another member function in graph so that bind expression became: bind(graph::transform, this, _1)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is with only the information you provided.
What is the signature of the `graph::transform` function you're trying to bind?

Comment: my_obj* graph::transform(edge_descriptor)

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to transform a range of edge descriptors to an equivalent (my_obj*). we have typedef std::pair<edge_iterator, edge_iterator> Edge_range; Edge_range all_edges